# Bootstrap navbar menu no collapse on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with collapsing bootstrap nav bar menu. I am creating theme for wordpress and bootstrap navbar is not working. bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js are loaded in functions. Here is my code:

```
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/logo.png" class="logo">
        </a>
    </div>

    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'navbar',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
    );
    ?>
</div>
</nav>
```

And it create this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vCac.png)

Anyone idea what is wrong? (i need it inline -i know how to do it, but main problem is, that button that collapse menu on small devices doesn't work). 
Thanks for help

Comment: The id given in `data-target` is not matching the id of the generated menu? Can you show us the html that is generated by `wp_nav_menu()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" id="top"><img alt="Company Logo" src="<?php echo (get_template_directory_uri() . '/assest/imgs/logo/e4k-logo.png');?>" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'menu'              => 'primary',
                        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                        'depth'             => 3,
                        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );                      
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I've taken this straight from one of my WordPress Themes, if however this doesn't work then it must be the way you have loaded your bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js in your functions.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with bad loading scripts, so now it is working with your code.